# Transaction too large: 1876 -- Need Help

Tags: solana-program, staking, transaction, rewards

Please help. I unstaked SOL on TrustWallet from 5 or so delegators at once.  Since then, when I go to claim my rewards, I receive the following error:  encoded solana_sdk::transaction::versioned::Versioned-Transaction too large: 1876 bytes (max: encoded/raw 1683/1232). There's no option to separate the transactions in TrustWallet. Please help!
-A Noob

Comment: You may need to go to their support to figure this out if they don't give an option. The network is strict on transaction sizes

Comment: Thanks Jon C.  I've been going to their support for last two months, with no results to speak of thus far.  I just get the same boilerplate responses and then they close my trouble ticket without resolving my issue.

Comment: You can probably export private key of your trust wallet and import it in phantom.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been more than a year and isn't a problem related to solana itself but rather a wallet provider.